# Alternatives to FastDateFormat for efficient date parsing?

Tags: java, performance, parsing, date

Well aware of performance and thread issues with `SimpleDateFormat`, I decided to go with `FastDateFormat`, until I realized that `FastDateFormat` is for formatting only, no parsing!

Is there an alternative to `FastDateFormat`, that is ready to use out of the box and much faster than `SimpleDateFormat`?

I believe `FastDateFormat` is one of the faster ones, so anything that is about as fast would do.

Just curious , any idea why `FastDateFormat` does not support parsing? Doesn't it seriously limit its use?

Comment: Note: As of lang 3.2, this question & answer are now obsolete.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At a best guess, it's to keep FastDateFormat... well... fast, by limiting it to display only.

Apache Commons `DateUtils` has a `parseDate` function, but that uses `SimpleDateFormat` internally.

An alternative is to use the [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library.  It's a complete replacement for dealing with `DateFormat`, `Date`, and `Calendar` objects.

JodaTime has a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) that can be used to create [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) objects (JodaTime's equivalent of Java's `Date` objects) from strings.

An example of how to use it is like this:

```
String strInputDateTime = "2010-12-27"; // An example, this would really come from outside
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(strInputDateTime);
```

I don't know if this is really any faster than `SimpleDateFormat`, though.

Comment: Note: As of lang 3.2, this question and answer are now obsolete.

Comment: Is that lenient or *non-lenient*?

Comment: As of Java 8, you should use the default `DateTimeFormatter` instead of `JodaTime`. (The new Java 8 Time API was designed primarily by the author of `JodaTime`)

Answer (score 22):

Note that since commons-lang 3.2, FastDateFormat supports parsing as well as printing.

See: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html

Comment: surprise surprise, Apache has FastDateParser as well for parsing

Comment: I painfully discovered that the parsing is case sensitive. (10Jan10 works. 10JAN10 no). The bug is fixed in 3.4  but at the time of this comment I is not realeased or in Maven. Looking forward for it.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-996

Comment: I may be wrong but as of 3.4 there seems to be no way to set the _lenient_  property of your  FastDateParser to **false**.

Answer (score 10):

Found something interesting here of this case in Android:
http://andmob.wikidot.com/faq-simpletimeformat

> SimpleDateFormat, the first time you
>   try parsing (or, presumably,
>   formatting) a date, will load in all
>   the timezone data for your locale.
>   This will take 2-3 seconds. It is
>   hoped that this will be fixed in some
>   future edition of Android.
>
> In the interim, consider using
>   AsyncTask to "warm up"
>   SimpleDateFormat in your process
>   before you need it. Just parse some
>   date in the AsyncTask doInBackground()
>   to get it to load the timezones
>   sometime when it will not impact the
>   user so much. Once initialized in your
>   process, SimpleDateFormat will run
>   quickly until your process is
>   terminated.

Comment: That's interessting, +1 for that! But this issue is Android specific and slightly off topic, isn't it?

Answer (score 8):

As of Java 8, one can use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) along with the the [Java 8 Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) to both parse and format dates. From the documentation:

> This class is immutable and thread-safe.

It's recommended to use this class if possible for new work going forward instead of using SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 3):

The 'problem' with SimpleDateFormat is not performance, its thread safety.

If you have thousands of threads and synchronizing is not an issue use synchronized (you can also pool the instances to alleviate this a little)

If you have a reasonable amount of threads the recommended way is to have a separate instance for each SimpleDateFormat.

**UPDATE**

As of Java 8, just use `DateTimeFormatter`. It is immutable, thread safe, faster, and more flexible. (It also offers nice features like default patterns for ISO-8601 date/time strings.)

Comment: Since SimpleDateFormat is thread-unsafe, you'd need to create a new instance or synchronize concurrent access to a shared instance. It's pretty slow either way. That's what I meant by performance issue.

Comment: Depends on your situation, but if you just need one (which is why I suppose you need a thread safe version), you can instantiate a new one at the beginning of each thread and reuse the same one within that thread. If you have thousands of threads being initialized then the overheads of creating a thread is much higher than creating the actual SimpleDateFormat object instance.

Comment: Simple: Always use ThreadLocal with SimpleDateFormat. (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

Comment: If you are running in a web container, then you'll want to take care with the use of ThreadLocals: http://blog.maxant.co.uk/pebble/2008/09/23/1222200780000.html

Comment: @michaelok AFAICT, TL can be used in a safe manner, but it's [pretty ugly](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62208/ugly-optimized-caching-of-simpledateformat).

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to parse dates that quickly?  Have you tested SimpleDateFormat and found it too slow for your needs?

Note, there are a variety of ways to cache slow-to-construct, non-thread-safe class instances (e.g. ThreadLocal, pools).

Comment: I realize that there are some techniques that involve pooling or multi-threading, but I'm looking for something off the shelf.

Comment: what about my other question?  have you confirmed that SimpleDateFormat is too slow for your needs?

Comment: +1 for ThreadLocal and "do you really need performance here".

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is pretty slow, if you want to do intensive Date format and parsing for example serialize a big object tree to JSON String. SimpleDateFormat internally uses StringBuffer which is not optimal.