# Parsing RSS pubDate in Android slow with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, android-date, android-dateutils

I need to parse `pubDate` from RSS feeds in an Android App. Unfortunately, the `pubDate` is formatted differently in different RSS feeds (e.g. `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z`, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz`...)

I have found a solution to parse most different date formats with the [DateParser.java](https://java.net/projects/rome/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/java/com/sun/syndication/io/impl/DateParser.java?rev=840) which uses `SimpleDateFormat`. However, this implementation is really slow since it does not cache the `SimpleDateFormat` instances (as recommended for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650589/parsing-many-date-items?lq=1)).

Any ideas how I can parse all possible date formats faster and avoid reinventing the wheel? Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fixed `DateParser.java` can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-rome-feed-reader/issues/detail?id=1#c9). Here is how the problem was fixed by the contributor:

> I modified com.sun.syndication.io.impl.DateParser to use a cache with a limited size for keeping existing SimpleDateFormat objects and will clone them when needed to avoid using constructor method.